# Ria Service: Navigation Property is null

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

For example I have two entities

```
Class A
{
 public Guid Id {get;set;}
 public Guid BId {get;set;}
 public B InstanceB {get;set;}
}

Class B
{
 public Guid Id {get;set}
}
```

B is related to A, on my silver light application I am creating a new instance of A, and also a new instance of B. The new instance of B does not exist yet. But I need the instance of B on my service.

Can I do this without Entity or Association with Ria Service?

**Edit:**

My Class A :

public partial class lSync{

```
        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private lSync() {
        }

        public string ConflictMessage { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateInserted { get; set; }

        public Guid vValuesId { get; set; }

        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public bool IsConflict { get; set; }

        public bool IsReadyToSync { get; set; }

        public Guid SyncSet { get; set; }

        public vValues vValues { get; set; }

    }
```

My Ria Service:

[Invoke]
 public lSync[] SynchvValuesFromClient(lSync[] syncs) {

```
        bool noConflict = true;
        foreach (lSync sync in syncs) {
            var servervValue = GetvValuesByID(sync.vValuesId).FirstOrDefault();
            var queuevValues = sync.vValues; //sync.vValues here is null, but my sync.vValuesId is not
            if (servervValue== null) {
                InsertvValues(queueValue);
            }
            else {
                if (servervValue.IsServerConflict(queueValue)) {
                    sync.IsConflict = true;
                    sync.ConflictMessage = "Conflict";
                    noConflict = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (!servervValue.AreValuesEqual(queueValue)) {
                    UpdatevValues(queueValue);
                }
            }
        }

        if (noConflict) {
            this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return syncs;
    }


    public IQueryable<vValues> GetvValuesByID(Guid ID) {
        return ObjectContext.vValues.Where(t => t.ID == ID);
    }


    public void InsertvValues(vValues model) {
        model.ServerDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if ((model.EntityState != EntityState.Detached)) {
            this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model, EntityState.Added);
        }
        else {
            this.ObjectContext.vValues.AddObject(model);
        }
    }


    public void UpdatevValues(vValuesmodel) {
        model.ServerDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.ObjectContext.vValues.AttachAsModified(model,               this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(model));
    }
```

:(

Comment: What do you mean by Can I do this without Entity or Association with Ria Service?

Comment: Sorry if this is not clear, what I am currently doing is that B is a navigation property of A, in Entity framework. But in my scenario, A is a new object, and so is B. so both of them are not yet in the db. So when I pass them to RIA service InstanceB is always null.

Comment: First create B than create A than set A.InstanceB = B. The order matters because calling SubmitChanges will insert B first so A would have a valid link to B.

Comment: Yup, but once I pass the instance of A to Ria service, B is sudenly null. I also try doing just a poco and adding the Include and Association attribute but still B is always null once I pass it to Ria service

Comment: How are you using the DomainService? Can you tell me how you create the context, add, call submit and save changes? Does B show up in the database, even tough not connected to A?

Comment: The method I am using accepts an array of A that will be processed. Nothing is saved yet, I am just passing A to the Ria Service, but the foreach of those A, my B is always null, but on the line of code before I call the ria service, I checked that A has an instance of B.

Comment: My guess is that because B is a navigation property of A, and B doesn't exist yet so Entity Framework or Ria is setting it to null. But there is a value of A.BId, only B is missing :(. I tried removing the class A from entity framework and made it a complex object instead but for B to be usable on the other side, I need to add Include and Association tag and still B is still null.

Comment: Why is there no `[Include]` attribute on public vValues vValues { get; set; }? Are you trying to send over A with B attached via parameter? Why not use the generated insert method for `B` at the **client side** and than use the generated insert method for `A` at the client side. Both in the same context on the client side and than submit/save.

Comment: I also tried include already, I can not save changes client side, I need to do it on the server using Ria Services. Actually A would never be saved, it is just a placeholder for B.

Comment: If `B` is an entity and `A` not than try adding the `[Key]` attribute on the id of `A` this way A will behave like an entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

The order is wrong of your method :)
Make an instance of the service before creating instances of the Entities.

It should be:

```
public void SyncToServer() { 
  ContextService service = new ContextService();
  var instanceA = new A(); 
  instanceA.InstanceB = new B(); 
  service.SubmitChanges(); //service.SaveChanges() for LinqToEntities
}
```

Are you reloading after a submit because only adding the [Include] attribute in the DomainService MetaData won't work. You need to do this in the DomainService for LinqToSql

```
public A GetA()
{
  DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
  dlo.LoadWith<A>(a => a.InstanceB);
  this.DataContext.LoadOptions = dlo;
  return this.DataContext.APlural.FirstOrDefault( ); //don't know the plural of A.
}
```

LinqToEntities:

```
public A GetA()
{
  return this.MyEntitiesContext.APlural.Include( "instanceB" ).FirstOrDefault( ); //don't know the plural of A.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am passing from my silverlight app to ria service, I created an instance of A with B in silverlight then I pass it to ria, but when I am already checking it in ria I can't save B cause it is null. Note also that in my scenario both A and B doesn't exist yet in the database.

Comment: @arcbound08 than I need to know if your disposing your DataContext before you create the entities. Have you tried explicitly doing the next?: Make an instance of the datacontext, create B, than create A, set A.InstanceB = B and submit the changes, than dispose your context. All within a single method, please provide me some code to work with.

Comment: Thank you, I hope this can help In my silverlight:

public void SyncToServer()
{
   var instanceA = new A();
   instanceA.InstanceB =  new B();

    ContextService service = new ContextService();
    var result = service.ProcessA(instanceA);
}


in my Ria Service
[Invoke]
public int ProcessA(A instanceA)
{
 // Do Something  - > in this method instanceA.InstanceB is null
}

Comment: the ProcessA? this.ObjectContext.Bs.Add(instanceA.InstanceB) but sadly I am adding a null value here. I am not sure why it is happening.

Comment: @arcbound08 Please just change the order of creating things. Absolutely definitly create the context first or use ObjectContext.Bs.Attach(instanceB) and ObjectContext.As.Attach(instanceA), than Save

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new A(){
    B = new B(); //or (B)selectedItem
}
```

now a.Id and a.BId is 0 until you SaveChanged and return saved A